# How can I run docker-compose up as shell script by Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, docker-compose, devops

I am trying to run command `docker-compose up -d` as a build step of Jenkins, in "execute shell". Job fails and gives me following console log:

> docker-compose up --build -d
>   Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?
>
> If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
>   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE`

When I cd into jenkins workspace (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/app/) and tried to run docker-compose up, at first I could get a normal build. Right now I get error in console: `ERROR: Error processing tar file(archive/tar: invalid tar header):`. Of course app builds and runs normally in home directory when invoked from console.

Docker is running on host. It is possible to run docker-compose by regular user. I did add jenkins user to docker group. I even tried following some asian tutorial from http://blog.csdn.net/qiyueqinglian/article/details/46559825 that made me change DOCKER_OPTS in default/docker, but after restarting docker service it was not running on port 4243, so I didn't understood translation or it is not working on ubuntu 16.04 (host system).

Jenkins is not running in container, it is casually installed on host, no VM no docker, nothing. I tried removing docker and jenkins completly from host (purge etc) and reinstalling, still the same errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Go here `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/app/`,and do this: `sudo -u jenkins docker info`. Do you get any error?

Comment: Hey thanks for response. I got warning `WARNING: Error loading config file:/home/pwlaz/.docker/config.json - stat /home/pwlaz/.docker/config.json: permission denied`, and after this warning there is normal output of docker info (the same bunch of information I can get as myself, pwlaz). So I'm kind of lost, there is some permission denied but in the same time informations are printed

Comment: That's ok. The permission denied is because of the bad home dir. This will not fail: `sudo -H -u jenkins docker info`. I don't know what could be happening from jenkins app.

Answer (score 0):

Hit this command as a root user and try again

```
usermod -aG docker jenkins
```